# Dreamweaver CS6 Auto-Closing apostrophe issue

Tags: dreamweaver, code-completion

Just upgraded from Dreamweaver CS5.5 to Dreamweaver CS6, and this is a little thing, but its really starting to grate:

In CS5.5 whenever I opened apostrophes, it would auto-complete the closing apostrophe. Then whilst typing if I typed the closing apostrophe it would just skip past the auto-completed closing apostrophe.

eg: class="page"**|**  <--being the cursor

In CS6 however, when I type to the closing apostrophe it adds another apostrophe without skipping past the auto-completed closing apostrophe.

eg: class="page"**|**"  <-- the exact same sequence of keys typed as above, but results in this.

Is there any way to get CS6 mimicking the same behaviour as CS5.5?

Comment: I know this might be stupid and obvious but would it just be easier to ask adobe tech-support? It could be a bug a or they forgot to attend to this particular issue.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah this is possible, but I'm not using my windows machine right now (I'm in linux).
I'll go back home and follow up immediately, but to the best of my memory the options are in

> Edit -> Preferences

After that I think it was in "Code Hints"

One of the options there has the solution to your problem.

---

**Note on Dell/ASUS Machines**

Dell and ASUS sometimes implement this 'feature' where if you press ", it gets autocompleted. This interferes with dreamweaver. Then the only solution is to simply turn off code hints.. sorry.. :(

Comment: This was the first place I looked... no joy, nothing specifically for apostrophes - I can only completely turn on or off auto-completion, add a delay etc. unless I am missing something?

Comment: Let me just get back home, i'm sure i solved this sometime back. :)

Comment: Sorry i took so long to get back. Just out of curiosity, is it a dell machine you are using? Can you tell me the type of machine you are using (ASUS, Dell, etc).
There is a solution, but i want to confirm this first

Comment: its a custom built PC - why does this have a baring on this problem?

Comment: Cause dell and ASUS sometimes implement this 'feature' where if you press ", it gets autocompleted. This interferes with dreamweaver. Then the only solution is to simply turn off code hints.. sorry.. :(

Comment: dont you think that i might of noticed the same behaviour in dreamweaver CS5.5 if this was an issue with my machine?

Comment: okay.. sorry dude. I just wanted to check all possibilities. And i tried to help as much as possible. Didn't mean to offend